# What is the job market like in terms of research positions in the industry for continuous optimizers?

Tags: mathematics, job, industry

I know that PhDs in continuous optimization do find research positions at Amazon, Facebook, and Google. But that's just a few places, and I'm hoping to get a more comprehensive view of the research opportunities in industry. Are they more/less in number than academia jobs (such as postdocs, tenure-track positions)? How difficult/easy is it to get those jobs compared to postdocs and tenure-track positions?